# Why there are just two Ramachandran angles in protein structure for two peptide bonds?

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, biochemistry, structural-biology

I really want to understand why there are just two ramachandran angles to understand the structure of the protein and why not three or many ? Can someone suggest some reference and explain this ?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/40181/when-calculating-a-dihedral-angle-for-a-chemical-bond-how-is-the-direction-defi https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/28167/how-to-get-a-proteins-dihedral-angles-ordered-by-variance https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/485/what-is-c%ce%b2-c-beta-deviation

Comment: Is anything unclear for example, here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramachandran_plot This is rather trivial question.

Comment: Only two angles are needed because the -CONH- grouping  is assumed to be planar, which  generally holds true, so is a good assumption.